# Visual Studio find un-overriden pure virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I am designing a class which inherits from a few interfaces, each with many pure virtual functions. I want to be able to instantiate my class so I need to override all of the pure virtual functions it inherits. I would appreciate a way to highlight or display the functions I have not yet overridden in my derived class but I have not yet found one.

I've tried generating a class diagram to visually compare the functions in the derived class and the base classes. However, I'd prefer a more direct and elegant solution, especially as the project grows.

Here's a generalized example:

Foo.h

```
class Foo {
public:
  virtual int foo1() = 0;
  virtual int foo2() = 0;
  virtual int foo3() = 0;
  virtual int foo4() = 0;
  //...
  virtual int foo90() = 0;
};
```

Bar.h

```
class Bar : public Foo {
public:
  int foo1() override {
    return 4;
  }
  int foo2() override {
    //do stuff
  }
  //darn, I lost track of what I still need to implement!
};
```

Does Visual Studio have a way to automatically display which functions are still not overridden? Alternatively, if there's a compiler option to display an error/warning for each of the abstract functions that are preventing the instantiation of my class then that would be just as helpful.

Comment: why not simply try to create an instance? If you missed to provide an implementation your compiler will tell you

Comment: Yes, I do get the "cannot instantiate abstract class" error. But my goal is to find out exactly **which** functions I still need to implement. The compiler fails to provide this information.

Comment: what compiler are you using? I would also get nervous if the compiler didnt tell me what method is missing, but I never had this happening

Comment: see eg here with gcc: https://wandbox.org/permlink/YEFTdlBIaDcJ3bp8. Couldn't me more clear imho

Comment: The "cannot instantiate abstract class" error also contains a list of which functions are abstract.

Comment: the problem of this question is a false premise that this information would not be available. Maybe it isnt but then you need to tell us what compiler you are using and the fix would be to use a compiler that has some minimum quality standards ;)

Comment: offtopic: if your typical base class has 90 methods that need to be overriden you have more severe problems than finding the missing one in the derived :P

Comment: Yep, tested to be sure: CL will tell exactly what's missing: *"error C2259: 'b': cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members: 'void a::c(void)': is abstract see declaration of 'a::c'"* This with version 19.20 and should be the same for older ones too.

Comment: Just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833905/how-do-you-handle-a-cannot-instantiate-abstract-class-error-in-c) and one of the answers explains that VS hides the second part of the message in the error list. Time to go back to compiling from the command line

Comment: @jbinvnt "_VS hides the second part of the message in the error list._" Or use Output window, instead of error list.

Comment: Below, I gave an example.

Comment: Maybe not exactly the solution you're looking for, but in VS2022 (and maybe other versions), you can right-click the overriding class name, select "Quick Actions and Refactorings...", then choose "Implement all Pure Virtuals for class '...' ". It should then automatically create a stub for each of the functions you need to make a concrete class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual int foo1() = 0;
    virtual int foo2() = 0;
    virtual int foo3() = 0;
    virtual int foo4() = 0;
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    int foo1() override {
        return 4;
    }
    int foo2() override {
        //do stuff
    }
};
```

And you instanciate Bar:

```
int main()
{
    Bar b;
}
```

Visual Studio produces a C2259 compilation error, tells that you cannot instantiate abstract class and highlights ("due to the following member") that foo3() and foo4() are abstract:

```
1>C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp(115,9): error C2259: 'Bar': cannot instantiate abstract class
1>C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp(99): message : see declaration of 'Bar'
1>C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp(115,9): message : due to following members:
1>C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp(115,9): message : 'int Foo::foo3(void)': is abstract
1>C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp(95): message : see declaration of 'Foo::foo3'
1>C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp(115,9): message : 'int Foo::foo4(void)': is abstract
1>C:\Users\Amit\source\repos\Test\Test\Test.cpp(96): message : see declaration of 'Foo::foo4'
1>Done building project "Test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Good answer.  Note that (in Visual Studio) the Error List window might only show one C2259 error, but the Output window will show all of the offending functions that are abstract and need to be overridden.